# Redux: render compoent based on a condition

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my react-redux application, i have the following react component:

```
render(){

      return(<div style={this.setStyler()} >
                  {this.props.value}
            </div>);
  }
```

The `setStyler()` manipulate a reducer and return a value which should be applied as `css`.

The problem is, i face with the error:

```
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within  render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.
```

It seems that redux does not allow me to render component based on state condition. but i don't know how can i fix this issue?

**Update**:

```
setStyler(){
    if(this.props.activeWord!=this.props.wordId)
      return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal' };
    if(this.props.letterId>this.props.activeLetter && this.props.activeWord==this.props.wordId)
         return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal' };

    if(this.props.letterId==this.props.activeLetter && this.props.activeWord==this.props.wordId){
          if(this.props.value==this.props.newTypedLetter){
               this.props.color({ color:'green', fontWeight: 'bold' });  //change  reducer
               return { color:'green', fontWeight: 'bold' };
          }
          if(this.props.value!=this.props.newTypedLetter){
               this.props.color({ color:'red', fontWeight: 'bold' });     ////change  reducer
                return { color:'red', fontWeight: 'bold' };  
               }

    }
    if(this.props.letterId<this.props.activeLetter && this.props.activeWord==this.props.wordId)
            return this.props.letterColor;

  }
```

Comment: Difficult in help with the information provided. Add the setStyler() function code

Comment: The code you've provided won't cause the error you're seeing. Where else are you using setState() ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in this case you should try to call `this.setStyler()` from `constructor` and from `componentWillUpdate`. And then you simply should read the value from redux store from your `render` function.

This should do the job, but still is not the best approach IMO, due to you are making your component `fat`. You can try to read this post about [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) which will explain a pattern of designing your components.

The problem is that, you are trying to modify something from render function, Which is a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). This in Functional Programming paradigm, which react tries to follow, is an anti-pattern. And as you can see react tries to tell you exactly that through the error you received.

Comment: it seems that, u r right. I am trying to set a compoent state for it, but still i have problem